# How do i include the "Modified By" details in search results?

Tags: search-results

I want to add the "Modified Data" available in the hover panel to the results displayd in the Search Page for site search. Please let me know how to do it if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your own managed properties as follows :

1)Within the Search Service Application, click on ‘Metadata Properties’ in the left sidebar, under Queries and Results

2)Within the Metadata Property Mappings page, click New Managed Property

3)Provide a name and select the type of information (should correspond to the type of column/property to be mapped).

4)Then click the Add Mapping button, find the crawled property you want to add and select OK. If you can’t find your property, it hasn’t yet been indexed.